# Restore a snapshot from a VM, not the Host

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, hyper-v, powershell

I have a Hyper-V VM which needs to be restored to its previous snapshot daily. I would like to automate this process. I’ve heard of the [Powershell Management Library for Hyper-V](http://www.codeplex.com/PSHyperv) on Codeplex, but I am not sure it is what I am looking for exactly. The scripts seem to be runnable from the Host, the not VM. This is making sense, but I would prefer the VM itself to schedule, and restore the snapshot. Is it possible?

In brief, I would like to know if it is possible for a VM (not the Host) to restore a snapshot.

Thanks.

Comment: out of curiosity why would you want the guest to tell the host to restore itself and not rnu it right on the host? The host seems to me to be the place to run this not a guest.

Comment: The machine runs tests all day long. When the process is completed, I want the machine to restore to the latest snapshot and re-start the test suite.

Comment: so wouldn't it be safer to have the host see if the test was complete (maybe by polling the event log?) then restore then snap?

Answer (score 2):

Many of the commands in that Powershell library have a `-server` parameter. Provided that the guest VM has the proper access to the Host (through the firewall, WMI, etc), you could do something like:

```
$server = myhyperv.mydomain.com
$guest = "My Guest Machine"
choose-vmsnapshot $guest $server | apply-vmsnapshot
```